# How to convert geo location to x,y coordinates in the map image

Tags: image, geolocation, geocoding, geo

I have to calculate the position of geo location lies in the image in x,y pixel points on the basis of following information:

1. Lat1 and Long1 of the first calibraition point lies in the map image
2. Lat2 and Long2 of the second calibration point lies in the map image.
3. X1, distance from left of the image to first Lat1,Lat2 point.
4. Y1, distance from top of the image to first Lat1,Lat2 point.
5. X2, distance from left of the image to second Lat1,Lat2 point.
6. Y2, distance from top of the image to second Lat1,Lat2 point.

Now I have to calculate below items:
 1. Plot Geo location on the map in terms of pixel points.
 2. Calculate geo locations of all the corners of image.

[image: Map Image]

Any help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Isnt it just to take the distance and multiply it with the map scale? (I ask, I don't know)

Comment: But how to calculate map scale because I am getting above informations only.

Comment: That depends on the map (google, bing, apple, etc). For example, in Bing, you'd write something like this:  

resolution = (cos(latitude * pi/180) * 2 * pi * 3963.1905919430524) / (256 * 2^zoomlevel)

Comment: Actually I'm getting this information from third party source and it could be anything like plan of a colony. That would not be an actual map.

Comment: RE your lsat question: you can get latlng bounds of the map (method depends on the library you're using).

I would also set additional (virtual) waypoints along the bounds and calculate the distance between original point and these virtual points to calculate distance